# Return OAuth2 Error as JSON instead of XML

Tags: json, spring, spring-security-oauth2

I am implementing an RESTful Webservice which returns every content formatted as JSON. I am also using Spring OAuth2, but all error messages like invalid access token etc are returned in XML format. How can I return these OAuth2 errors as JSON?
By the way, the access tokens are returned as JSON String.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have faced the same problem.

After hours and hours of configuring it on server side we have found better way to migrate this nuisance.

Error messages for OAuth2 for Spring defaults to xml but with one simple trick you can change them to JSON: by sending `Accept: application/json` in request headers.

Hope I helped a bit.

Comment: @BigDong in our Angular app

Comment: You just save my life man!!! I'm testing my server using Postman and I just add this to the header... The response changed to JSON.